# No sound after installing AlmaLinux 8.8 and 9.2

Tags: audio, centos7, almalinux

Newbie to Stack Overflow here. Old Centos user, trying to migrate to AlmaLinux or Rocky Linux.

I have 2 tower PCs (one I built in 2011 and one in 2019) and Centos 7.9 runs fine on both and provides sound.
When I installed AlmaLinux and Rocky Linux (8.8 and 9.2) recently on separate partitions on both PCs, they provide sound on the 2011 PC (bios upgraded in 2017). But neither 8.8 or 9.2 have sound on the 2019 PC,
All OSes are on separate partitions and boot without issues. Now both PCs have 3 OSes - Centos7.9, Almalinux/Rocky Linux 8.8 and 9.2). If it was a hard ware issue, I expected the sound to fail for all 3 OSes on one PC. But for Centos 7.9 the sound works fine on both. For AlmaLinux and Rocky Linux sound works fine on the older PC but not on the newer one.
Upgraded BIOS on the newer PC but no luck. Any help would be appreciated, I don't know what else I can do. I am fairly comfortable with the command line.